# Background images display over pop up message

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've been working a project for quite some time and part of the website application is a review function. That why some of you may have noticed I have posted quite a few times with problems, so far, this community has been super helpful and I thank you for that

So right now what is happening is that image are displaying over my pop up div
as seen in the picture below[image]

The pop up with Rating and feedback needs to above the images and the images need to be tinted

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "";
}

@model IEnumerable<Siza.Models.Review>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon"s
          type="image/png"
          href="~/Content/favicon.ico" />

    <title>Siza</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS - Uses Bootswatch Flatly Theme: http://bootswatch.com/flatly/ -->
    <link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/css/freelancer.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

<!--JQuery Plugin-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/js/jquery.easyPaginate.js"></script>

    <!--Demo-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/normalize.css">



<script>
    $('#easyPaginate').easyPaginate({
        paginateElement: 'section',
        elementsPerPage: 3,
        effect: 'climb'
    });
</script>


<style>
        textarea {
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 100px;
            resize: none;
        }

        .demo-3 {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px
}

.demo-3 figure {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left:-50px
}

.demo-3 figure img {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    margin:-15px 0
}

.demo-3 figure figcaption {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box
}

.demo-3 figure h2 {
    font-family:'Lato';
    color:#fff;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:left
}

.demo-3 figure p {
    display:block;
    font-family:'Lato';
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:18px;
    margin:0;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left
}

.demo-3 figure figcaption {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:29px 44px;
    background-color:rgba(26,76,110,0.5);
    text-align:center;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(-180deg);
    transform:rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s
}

.demo-3 figure img {
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s
}

.demo-3 figure:hover img,figure.hover img {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg)
}

.demo-3 figure:hover figcaption,figure.hover figcaption {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(0);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(0);
    transform:rotateY(0)
}

.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}



h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  image-rendering: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 40%;
  overflow: auto;
}

screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}



    </style>




</head>



    @foreach (var item in Model)

    {



                <!--Popup window content-->
                <div id="@item.ReviewID" class="overlay">
                    <div class="popup">
                        <h4>Rating: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)</h4>
                        <h4>Feedback: </h4>
                        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="floating-label-form-group controls">@Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => item.Feedback, new { @readonly = true })</div>


                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <ul class="demo-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <h4 align="center"><a href="#@item.ReviewID">Review Number: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReviewID)</a></h4>
                        <br />
                        <figure>
                            <img src="~/Content/img/studentwellnessreviewcard.jpg" alt="">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h4>Author: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)</h4>



                            </div>



                            <figcaption>
                                <h4 align="center">Date Created: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</h4>

                            </figcaption>
                        </figure>

                        <hr />

                    </li>
                </ul>




    }
```

Any suggestions? I'm not so sure which css property to change to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add z-index property to .popup{}

```
     .popup {
margin: 70px auto;   
padding: 20px;   
background: #fff;   
border-radius: 5px;   
width: 30%;   
position: relative;   
transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
z-index: 1000; 
}
```

That should work!

Comment: I just tried that.. still not working unfortunately :/

Comment: try this:
z-index: 1000 !important;

Comment: Use inline css with quotation marks like

style="z-index:1000"

Comment: I figured it out. You need to add the z-index to all the component which make up the pop-up in the css :) thanks for the guide though. If i wasn't aware of the z-index then i never would have been able to figure out how to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The previous z-index is correct as a method but what you need to do is add

```
z-index: 1;
```

to the element that you want to be on the foreground
and then:

```
z-index: -1;
```

to the element you want hiding behind it. Sometimes you need to also specify a relative position, but not always. Try it out with your code and let me know.

Comment: This is what I did: 

`<h4 align="center" style = z-index: 1><a href="#@item.ReviewID">Review Number: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReviewID)</a></h4>` and : 

`<ul class="demo-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center nav navbar-nav" style="z-index: -1">
                    <li>
                        <h4 align="center"><a href="#@item.ReviewID">Review                         `

Comment: Since you have posted your whole html and css code and not only the required divs' code, I can't really understand what exactly you're doing wrong or correct, but what you just added (the z-indexes), did it work?